# Continuous functions with values in separable Banach space dense in $L^{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, functions, metric-spaces

Let $[0,1] \subset \mathbb R$ be a the compact interval in the real numbers $\mathbb R$.
We know that $C([0,1] \to \mathbb R)$ (the continuous function on $[0,1]$ with values in $\mathbb R$) are dense in $L^{2}  ([0,1] \to \mathbb R)$ (the usual Lebesgue space).

Now consider the Lebesgue space of functions on $[0,1]$, that take values in a separable Banach space $X$, i.e. $L^{2}  ([0,1] \to X)$.
This space is equipped with the norm $\int_{[0,1]} | f(t) |_{X}^{2} d t$, where $|.|_{X}$ is the norm on $X$.

Are the continuous functions with values in this space, i.e. $C([0,1] \to X)$, also dense in $L^{2}  ([0,1] \to X)$ ?

For a concrete example, I am in particular interested in $X = C([1,2] \to \mathbb R )$, i.e. is $C([0,1] \to C([1,2] \to \mathbb R ))$ dense in $L^{2}  ([0,1] \to C([1,2] \to \mathbb R ))$?

Edit: This question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632067/c-1-2-times-0-1-to-mathbb-r-dense-in-c-1-2-rightarrow-l2-0), by a different order of the spaces.

Comment: Please clarify the definition of a Polish space. It is normally not equipped with a norm. Do you mean a Banach space?

Comment: You are right, I am thinking of  separable Banach spaces.. Changed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Ignoring questions of measurability: Suppose $f:[0,1]\to X$ and $\int_0^1||f(t)||_X^2\,dt<\infty$.

Say $X_n$ is an increasing sequence of finite-dimensional subspaces of $X$ so that $\bigcup X_n$ is dense in $X$. For each $n$ choose $f_n:[0,1]\to X_n$ such that, say, $$||f_n(t)-f(t)||_X\le 2 d(f(t),X_n)$$for all $t\in [0,1]$. Note that $||f_n(t)||_X\le 3||f(t)||_X$. Since $||f_n(t)-f(t)||_X\to0$ for all $t$, dominated convergence shows that $$\int_0^1||f_n(t)-f(t)||_X^2\,dt\to0.$$

Since $X_n$ is finite-dimensional there certainly exists a continuous function $g_n:[0,1]\to X_n$ with $$\int_0^1||g_n(t)-f_n(t)||_X^2\,dt<\frac1n;$$this is immediate from the scalar-valued case. QED.

Comment: You wrote "Ignoring questions of measurability": What kind of measurability issues could occur and how to avoid them?

Comment: Surely you don't expect me to answer another question from you.

Comment: This must be a personal misunderstanding, see my comment on the other answer. When I am not convinced I ask  additional questions, like in the previous comment (and I don't just vote). I am always thankful for your answers.

Comment: There's the question of how we even _define_ the appropriate measurability for the original function $f:[0,1]\to X$. I've never really studied such things. I standard definition is "pointwise limit of a sequence of simple functions" ; here, given that $X$ is separable, I suspect that "inverse image of every open set is measurable" may be sufficient and/or equivalent.

Comment: Then when I say you should choose $f_n$ such that etc, there's the question of how we make certain that $f_n$ is measurable. Here I'm certain there's a simple solution, haven't thought about what it would be. (For $f_n$ there's no question about what measurability should mean, since $X_n$ is finite dimensional.)