# $C ([1,2] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb R)$ dense in $C ( [1,2] \rightarrow L^{2} ([0,1] \to \mathbb R))$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, continuity, banach-spaces

Let $[0,1] \subset \mathbb R$ be a the compact interval in the real numbers $\mathbb R$.
We know that $C([0,1] \to \mathbb R)$ (the continuous function on $[0,1]$ with values in $\mathbb R$) are dense in $L^{2}  ([0,1] \to \mathbb R)$ (the usual Lebesgue space).

Now consider the space of continuous functions on $[1,2]$ taking values in $L^{2}  ([0,1] \to \mathbb R)$ , i.e. $C ( [1,2] \rightarrow L^{2}  ([0,1] \to \mathbb R))$.

Is the space $C ([1,2] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb R)$ dense in $C ( [1,2] \rightarrow L^{2}  ([0,1] \to \mathbb R))$?

In other words:
Fix an arbitrary $f \in C ( [1,2] \rightarrow L^{2}  ([0,1] \to \mathbb R))$.
Can we find a sequence $f_{n} \in C ([1,2] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb R)$, such that 
$$\sup_{z \in [1,2]} \int_{[0,1]} ( f_{n} -f )^{2} (z,x) d x \rightarrow 0
?
$$

This question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632035/continuous-functions-with-values-in-separable-banach-space-dense-in-l2), by a different order of the spaces.

Comment: Your notation is weird.

Comment: Which notation would you prefer? $C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ instead of $C([0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Say $f_t\in L^2[0,1]$ for $t\in[1,2]$ and $f_t$ depends continuously on $t$. Then $K=\{f_t:t\in[1,2]\}$ is a compact subset of $L^2[0,1]$.

Define $T_n:L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$ by, say, letting $T_n=f*\phi_n$, where $\phi_n$ is an approximate identity. It's easy to see that for each $n$ the function $g_n(s,t)=T_nf_t(s)$ is continuous on $[0,1]\times[1,2]$. We know $T_nf\to f$ in $L^2$ for every $f\in L^2$. And since $||T_n||\le||\phi_n||_1=1$ the family $(T_n)$ is *equicontinuous* on compact subsets of $L^2$. Hence $T_nf\to f$ uniformly on $K$.

---

**???** Since the downvoter doesn't see fit to show the courtesy of explaining what he or she thinks the problem is I have to guess. There are all sorts of things above that could be read incorrectly. Take the conclusion, "Hence $T_nf\to f$ uniformly on $K$", for example. A person *could* think that said that a certain sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]\times[1,2]$ converged uniformly to a discontinuous function, which would of course be absurd. But that's not what it says. $K$ is a metric space, being a subset of the metric space $L^2$. $T_n$ is a sequence of mappings from this metric space into another metric space, again $L^2$ as it happens. So saying $T_nf\to f$ uniformly on $K$ says precisely that $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}||T_nf_t-f_t||_2\to0$.

Not that I have any reason to think that that's the problem, but I suspect that whatever the problem is is based on a similar sort of incorrect reading. Can't explain the actual problem without being told what it is...

Comment: Really? What's the problem?

Comment: It was not me who voted you down. I'll vote you +1, when I am convinced that your proof is correct. But the guy who down voted you confused me, that there might be a problem I don't see....

Comment: It might be better to base your opinions on the math instead of the votes you see. It happens that people cast votes for all sorts of reasons. I've certainly had people point out errors or gaps in comments, which is as it should be. I don't think it's ever happened that someone downvoted a post of mine without explanation, and then it turned out there was a valid reason. In one case the guy said "I thought it was wrong", with _nno_ explanation of what was wrong. In other cases the explanation, that the guy never explicity admitted, was "I didn't understand it so it must be wrong".

Comment: Or "I was pissed off that you answered the question I asked instead of the question I had in mind."